# How to do an sql jointure on spark?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to do an SQL joint between two tables in spark, and I got an unexpected error :

```
>>> cyclistes.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: string (nullable = true)
(...)
>>> voyages.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- vitesse: string (nullable = true)
 (...)
>>> requete_sql = """
SELECT c.id, c.age, mean(v.vitesse)
FROM   cyclistes as c , voyages as v
WHERE c.id == v.id
GROUP BY c.id
"""
>>> spark.sql(requete_sql)


   AnalysisException: "grouping expressions sequence is empty, and 
'c.`age`' is not an aggregate function. Wrap '(avg(CAST(v.`vitesse` 
AS DOUBLE)) AS `avg(CAST(vitesse AS DOUBLE))`)' in windowing 
function(s) or wrap 'c.`age`' in first() (or first_value) if you 
don't care which value you get.;
```

Any idea ?

### ANSWER :

Basic error in the SQL query : 
should be added a max around age :

```
    >>> requete_sql = """ 
SELECT c.id, max(c.age), mean(v.vitesse) 
FROM  cyclistes as c , voyages as v 
WHERE c.id == v.id GROUP BY c.id """
>>> spark.sql(requete_sql)
```

Comment: All the columns those are NOT part of "GROUP BY" clause should have aggregation function (eg. MIN, MAX, SUM etc.) in "SELECT" clause.

Answer (score 0):

### ANSWER :

Basic error in the SQL query : 
should be added a max around age :

```
    >>> requete_sql = """ 
SELECT c.id, max(c.age), mean(v.vitesse) 
FROM  cyclistes as c , voyages as v 
WHERE c.id == v.id GROUP BY c.id """
>>> spark.sql(requete_sql)
```